# HTTPS in display is red crossed line with AWS ubuntu

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate

I have generated a .key file, .csr file and .crt file from following URL:

https://serversforhackers.com/self-signed-ssl-certificates

I skip steps for shell script file.

All 3 files are generated successfully and `ssl` host is generated successfully. Now I open my domain with `https` it display me some success part and some error part like following image:

[image]

When I click on certification information I show following info

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a self-signed certificate. That's what the browser is going to show for a self-signed cert. If you don't want a browser warning you will have to use a certificate from a verified certificate authority.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Suppose i am buying it https://www.comodo.com/. what they provide me? .crt, .csr and .crt files? i am confused in that. please explain me in details.